# Bootstrap padding not showing with tabs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello i am having a weird issue here i have a  i have created e form inside it but the padding does not display.

[image]

This is my html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <tabset tab-theme="orange" tab-position="top" style="border:none!important;">
        <tab heading="Person">
            <form class="form-horizontal">

                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- Text input-->
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="first_name">First Name</label>
                                <input id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="Type here.." class="form-control" required="" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Text input-->
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                                <input id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Type here.." class="form-control" required="" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Text input-->
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="other_name">Other Name</label>
                                <input id="other_name" name="other_name" placeholder="Type here.." class="form-control" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
        </tab>
        <tab heading="Company">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores porro eveniet debitis quas sed harum nobis libero voluptatibus dolorum odio at veniam aut id corrupti hic esse quisquam fugiat. Asperiores in eveniet sapiente error fuga tenetur ex ea dignissimos voluptas ab molestiae eos totam quo dolorem maxime illo neque quia itaque.</p>
            </div>
        </tab>
    </tabset>
</div> <!-- container-fluid -->
```

There is usually padding my default for each form input container.  In this case there is not.

I do not know it it is an issue with my html or css, is there a specific way of doing this or do i have to force the padding from my CSS?

Comment: Where do you want padding. Can you specify in image

Comment: In between the form inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bootstrap Documentation for Form Horizontal](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)

> Use Bootstrap's predefined grid classes to align labels and groups of
>   form controls in a horizontal layout by adding .form-horizontal to the
>   form (which doesn't have to be a ). Doing so changes
>   .form-groups to behave as grid rows, so no need for .row.

If you read Bootstrap's doc. its clearly mentioned that, .form-group inside .form-horizontal acts as .row, hence, you col-md-xx are not getting their padding.
as per your code:

```
.row {margin-left:-15px;margin-right:-15px} // margin goes negative
.col-md-xx {padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px} // padding creates 30px gutter
.form-group {margin-left:-15px;margin-right:-15px} // again your margins go negative - hence no gutter.
```

Better remove **form-horizontal** class or overwrite it with your custom css

working Codepen example: http://codepen.io/happy2deepak/pen/wKwYXJ?editors=100

Comment: Yup this was the answer only with this i need to add a .clear-fix to the bottom of my tab content otherwise it displays wrong, other alternative is to take out the form-group wrapper instead. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your html remove container of `div.form-group` .if you remove both containers `div.row` and `div.col-md-4` your inputs will be rendered with form default padding.
Also add class `form-inline` to form tag and remove class `form-horizontal`.
Try this solution it will work

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <tabset tab-theme="orange" tab-position="top" style="border:none!important;">
 <tab heading="Person"> 
<form class="form-inline"> 
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label" for="first_name">First Name</label> 
<input id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="Type here.." class="form-control" required="" type="text">
  </div>
 <!-- Text input-->
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="last_name">Last Name</label> 
 <input id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Type here.." class="form-control" required="" type="text"> 
</div>
 <!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label" for="other_name">Other Name</label> 
<input id="other_name" name="other_name" placeholder="Type here.." class="form-control" type="text"> 
</div> 
</form>
 </tab> 
<tab heading="Company">
 <div class="col-xs-12">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores porro eveniet debitis quas sed harum nobis libero voluptatibus dolorum odio at veniam aut id corrupti hic esse quisquam fugiat. Asperiores in eveniet sapiente error fuga tenetur ex ea dignissimos voluptas ab molestiae eos totam quo dolorem maxime illo neque quia itaque.</p> 
</div>
 </tab>
 </tabset> 
</div>
 <!-- container-fluid -->
```

Comment: If i do this i cannot get my inputs into three different columns like in the picture plus it still does not fix the padding issue.

Comment: Yes i did exactly that.

Comment: One more thing add class `form-inline` to your form element

Comment: To which form element in particular?

Comment: You have to remove class `form-horizontal` from form tag.

Comment: See updated answer after removing `form-horizontal` class. This will hopefully work

Answer (score 0):

Well i couldn't find the cause and the right solution so i just forced the padding in my CSS:

```
.form-horizontal .form-group {
    padding: 10px !important;
}
```

Found the issue. it was with the "form-group" wrapper.
I took it out, now the padding displays properly.

Comment: Has nothing to do with it. Bootstrap has negative margins (left and right) of `-15px` declared for `.form-horizontal .form-group { ... }`. See my answer you down voted. lol

Comment: I actually tried your solution, all it did was remove the margins at the sides.  Didn't solve the no-padding issue.

Comment: Then I clearly don't understand what you're trying to accomplish as I thought you wanted spacing between the input textboxes. The negative margining was what was causing the textboxes to nudge next to each other.

Answer (score -1):

It's your parent container `<form>` that has the class of `.form-horizontal`. Bootstrap (by default) has negative margins set for that. Below is a snippet of the style sheet that is causing the behavior of your input boxes.

```
.form-horizontal .form-group {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

You can either:

1. Remove the `form-horizontal` class from the form element. OR;
2. Add the following to your custom style sheet to over write the default declaration, like this:

   `.form-horizontal .form-group {
       margin-right: 0;
       margin-left: 0;
   }`

Here's a fiddle demo for you to review. http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/Lt0o5mp0/

Comment: I don't understand what this does is get rid of the margins at the sides, what i want is to restore the default "padding" in between form inputs.

Comment: The style sheet I included is something in vanilla Bootstrap. You can 1.) Remove the `.form-horizontal` group from the `<div>`, or add your own class to over-write the default negative margin. Here's a fiddle with the negative margin. I will update my answer too. http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/Lt0o5mp0/

Comment: I don't want to touch my margins, my problem is padding.

Comment: Then remove the `form-horizontal` class, as suggest in #1 above. lol

Comment: Yes the thing is i have tried all that.  Form horizontal is not the cause of the no padding problem. I did some fiddling around and took out the form-group wrapper and realized that was the cause it displays properly now. I use bootsnipp to quickly generate all my forms all the time and i've never before had this issue. :)